# 2 year old still drooling, what can i do?

Tags: speech

I have a child of two years and still drooling, at first I did not care much but I fear that this will become a habit or interfere with their ability to speak. I already visited the pediatrician and ruled out any problem with adenoids. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: Is your child still teething? Drooling can continue all the way through teething...

Comment: All the males in my immediate family are famous for drooling.  I have three brothers (now married, with children) and they all drooled for a very long time.  One brother still does, occasionally.  Not sure why just the boys (maybe girls are more susceptible to social embarrassment?) but it may just be general absentmindedness (they are extremely high IQ but not too observant)

Comment: he already has all his teeth @RoryAlsop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some children will produce more saliva than others - leads to drooling. It is because, the ability to swallow isn’t developed in most of the children at this age. This might be one of the reason and another reason would be the child may be cutting his 2 year molars. Once your child develops the ability to swallow and his molars come in then the drooling stops.

To develop the swallowing ability let your child to have sips of water frequently throughout the day. This may help him.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it seems you are right, this happens for his ability to swallow, since taking liquids from a cup, he always chokes. I will try to make him a drink fluids glass more often.

Answer (score 3):

My pediatrician recommended to have my son drink from straws (there are sippy cups with straws) as it can be a sign of 'lazy' (underdeveloped) jaw muscles and sucking on a straw works those muscles.  His mouth tended to relax when he was concentrating on something else and then he drooled and it didnt bother him. It has helped with the drooling.